# Is there a need for buffering in this case?

Tags: sensor, buffer, data-acquisition

.. will be updated soon (in construction with a more accurate information)

If the ADC (or the data.acq device) have 100 kohm input impedance, how much accuracy would I lose?

Do I need to buffer this for a better accuracy?

I'm kind of confused to relate the accuracy g and the output voltage here. I would be glad if someone may explain it for a novice.

Setup will be as shown:

..will be updated

There is an interface box for connector input outputs and a dual power supply for the transducers. Number of transducers will be much more but for simplicity I drew two of them. The interface box and the data-acq. board can be very close to each other no prob.

But the transducers (floating wrt the earth) will be around 400 meter away from the box and daq as you see above. A CAT6 twisted shielded cable will be used for each transducer. In the diagram I named the letters for the transducers which corresponds their pins from the datasheet I linked.

The manufacturer states the output impedance as 1 kohm and says load can be 100 kohm.
But isn't that a huge problem for accuracy?

I need an accuracy of 0.4 mV.

I'm kind of ignorant about how to interpret the datasheet to the accuracy and impedance of the transducer and ADC. Does this device need calibration or everything is already in datasheet? Is it possible to achieve around 0.4 mV accuracy?

*power ground and signal ground of the transducers (B and F) are internally connected I checked with a multi meter test.

Comment: What would your guess be? Something like 1/101? What accuracy are you expecting from the sensor anyway? Any sources of high level interfering signals nearby?

Comment: Yes I would think that voltage divider way. Is that correct? But the manufacturer recommends 100k load that shocked me since it means huge error. Isnt it? But Im ignorant about these sensors and have a bit hurry for the setup. I edited my answer with all details. The cables will not be on air and they will be indoors on a bridge. But I will use diff ended input daq for common mode issues ect. Please see my edit.

Comment: 0.4mV on what signal level? 0.4mV on it's own is meaningless... Further, over 400m will be a much bigger issue. You should consider local capture.

Comment: Interest of freq is less than 1Hz.

Comment: .4mV on 7.5V is rather a ridiculous accuracy.... 0.005%. What are you really trying to do?

Comment: @Trevor_G You mean it is not achievable? Im not experienced in this matter. I would be glad to see your answer as well.

Comment: I have a feeling you are confusing resolution with accuracy.

Comment: @Trevor_G It could be, I feel damn confused on many things right now.

Comment: @Trevor_G The purpose was to detect 0.15Hz motion down to 0.022mG.

Comment: It may be better to explain in the question what this is supposed to do.... Measuring  22uG on a .1G sensor is a bit like trying to measure a fraction of an ounce of flour on a truck scale.

Comment: @Trevor_G You are right but I didnt know that. What should be the "accuracy expectation" from a 0.1G sensor? And why? Since these based on experience I couldn't learn from the tutorials I encountered.

Comment: The tolerance of the device itself is only 1%.. i.e +-0.5mG. Whether you can detect 0.4mV of 0.15Hz modulation on that is another matter. But doing that from 400m is not a simple matter.

Comment: @Trevor_G: The scale factor accuracy of the device is irrelevant, since that can be calibrated out later, if necessary. The relevant specification is *"Threshold & Resolution: Better Than 1 µG"*.

Comment: @DaveTweed I did not see that line, so it should be good to detect small vibrations, but accuracy is still 1% over the range. However, the OP is mixing up accuracy and sensitivity/resolution making the question off-base.

Comment: @newage without more details, I think you are overlooking all sources of error and thus sources of solutions are being excluded

Comment: Basically your problem lacks sufficient specs for Noise ingress, for protection and SNR requirements. There will be other issues. such as optimum shield termination at one end only or both ends from any source of induced EMF. Telephone technology is very robust with CM hybrid transformers , but you are dealling with signals well below this.

Answer (score 2):

You need a *resolution* of 0.4 mV in order to detect your signal. Accuracy is a different question.

The voltage divider created by the source and load impedances introduces a constant gain error factor that can be calibrated out by applying a correction factor later.

As long as your DAQ has at least 16 bits of resolution, you should be good to go. Since your measurement bandwidth is so low, most sources of noise can be filtered out, and since you're not looking for DC signals either, offsets can be removed as well. All of this (1 Hz low-pass, 0.001 Hz high-pass, gain correction) can be done in the digital domain, after the ADC.

Comment: I think Im confused between the accuracy and resolution here. The ADC I can use is 16 bit +-10V which is enough for that resolution.

Comment: Can I find that voltage divider factor by applying a known DC through that 400m cable and compare it to what the daq measures?

Comment: +1 Agreed... assuming, that is, the device itself is capable of detecting such small changes at such a low frequency. Some simple bench testing is warranted here.

Comment: @newage2000: No, because such a measurement would not include the source impedance of the sensor itself. Furthermore, there are other sources of gain error that you need to account for as well, such as the sensor's own scale factor tolerance of 1%. If you really need to measure the amplitude of the vibration to that level of accuracy (as opposed to merely detecting it), then you need to put the sensor on a calibrated shaker table and work out the required correction factor from that.

Comment: @Trevor_G "To buffer or not to buffer thats the question" :))

Comment: @newage2000 as Dave and I have pointed out, you need to do some bench testing. Also, if you decide to add a PCB at the sensor end, going one step further to add a micro and do the detection remotely becomes much more attractive and makes the 400m much less of an issue.

Comment: Okay so for each transducer, I will make a 1Hz measurement with 0.5 meter cable and then same measurement with the 400m cable(rolled off straight) and then I will find the correction factor?

Comment: Arrgh! Somehow, I'm not making myself clear. It isn't the resistance of the cable that is the issue here -- it is many orders of magnitude less than the source and load impedances.

Comment: @DaveTweed I see. But I can access a calibrated accelerometer. They normally calibrate other accels comparing to this reference one. They attach them next to eachother and then give oscillation and calibrate others using this reference one on the same setup.  I guess I can use this method? I don have a calibrated shaker table.

Comment: Yes, that would be fine. A shaker table with a calibrated sensor on it is equivalent to a calibrated shaker table.

Answer (score 0):

High impedance signals on long cables are likely to carry unintended noise from stray E fields far exceeding your signal.

### Recommendation

Buffer the 1k source impedance (1mA ~15V) going into 400m of CAT6 into 100kOhm. The source impedance Z(f) will be near zero but 200 Ohms for RF where there is no feedback gain and no desired signal. I assume the CAT6 cables supply +/-15V DC on 3 wires with 1mA load.

Noise ingress can be caused by high CM noise being converted to DM noise by unbalanced impedance, so that a differential source and receiver is goping to improve this depending on CM/DM impedance ratios * % mismatch * source E field strength and Z(f) of shunt filter.

A magnetic CM SMD choke is adviseable somewhat like those used in telephony to reduce ingress noise and hope to achieve 400uV of noise max.

### **The purpose was to detect 0.15Hz motion down to 0.022mG.**

+/- 7.5V/100mG Full scale. using +/-15V supply.
0.22mG=7.5/100mG = 16.5mVp with Error budget 0.4mV = **SNR=41= 32 dB**

.

- AC line ingress ...  are there power lines nearby 3V/m or less?
- RF AM modulation ingress getting rectified into high impedance ESD protection diodes. Telemetry  nearby?

Since the most important informtion is the self-resonant frequencies of the bridge where displacement is double integral of acceleration so the mG level of 0.15Hz has a double amplitude (DA) or 2D @ 1.5Hz which is 10x larger f and 100x larger 2D at 0.15Hz.  So the key signal of the bridge vibration is not just A(f) but rather D(f) which is the 2nd integral of A(f). this results in a Displacement amplitude of ....

\$2D=\dfrac{A}{{(\pi f)}^2}\$

My suggestion is to propose a pre-emphasis on the signal just as RIAA did to phonograph recording and  FM broadcast does for HF audio in order to improve the spectral SNR.

Except here you want to pre-emphasize the ULF for the desired end result is D, displacement which is the Strain Displacement on the bridge. In otherwords a double integrator with DC restoration.

Re-consider acceleration normally done on bridges is  a LPF to block above 20Hz so that phase is preserved at 0.2Hz which is needed 2 decades above the main signal. blocking at 1Hz will result in Group Delay errors computing Displacement at 0.15Hz.

A better way is to use 2 integrators with DC restoring from drift to achieve a BW of 0.002 to 20 Hz ( 4 decades) that is now 40dB better SNR at 0.2Hz after 2nd order integration.  Due to group delay in such filters phase error must be considered in the passband by locating breakpoints 2 decades away on either side in order to reduce Phase Error.

Now the telemetry signal with a small PCB is Displacement D(t) instead of G(t) with much higher SNR desired for your application with pre-emphasis at source.

EMC protection is necessary with IEC ingress , but that's another question.

Comment: Interest of freq is less than 1Hz. Still valid what you write?

Comment: THen it is more an issue of SNR , what is your spec at minimum signal.?

Comment: HIs quoted accuracy numbers are nigh impossible.

Comment: Work out max signal and resulting SNR requirements.

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 Is there an adhoc IC you know for such purposes?

Comment: There can be 30 of these transducers. It will be painful to make buffers filters

Comment: @newage2000 Why should it be painful? Making a bunch of little PCBs that attach to the top of the sensor is not a big deal, especially when they are powered sensors anyway.

Comment: I have done seismic recording before, is that what this is for>?

Comment: basically bridge monitoring. cables will be indoors on the bridge not outdoors.

Comment: OK then there could be sensor resonance noise that will saturate the sensor 50~100Hz and bridge and wind impulse noise that will look random , where as you are only interested in < 1Hz so Noise rejection filter is necessary  Have you tested it yet on any bridge with traffic? the vibration spectrum is much wider

Comment: I used to test my Seismic amplifiers by flexing my knees on concrete 2 meters away, I could peg the needle.

Comment: no its the first time im dealing and such length of cables is the most scary part. we tried wireless transducers but they had other issues for such distances.

Comment: I suggest before you commit to a design to test 1 sensor on any bridge during rush hour on 500m CAT cable. and get a DSO with spectral analyzer It will need a CM choke

Comment: @Trevor_G "Making a bunch of little PCBs that attach to the top of the sensor" Are you talking about buffering and filtering? Why did you say "attach to the top of the sensor"? Isnt buffering or filtering done just before the input to the ADC?

Comment: Yes, @Trevor_G is suggesting doing the ADC there as well, and making the communication with the data gathering point purely digital. This eliminates most of the issues that you're worrying about.

Comment: @newage2000 since you are dealing with microvolt levels the more you can do locally and tightly to the sensor the better. Ultimately, sending digital information would be better.

Answer (score 0):

*Turning comments into an answer before the comment threads get migrated to chat...*

---

You are confusing accuracy and resolution/sensitivity.

According to the part spec the accuracy over the full range is only 1%, so if you are trying to measure and display 0.022mG of force you are using the wrong sensor. You may be able to calibrate it to closer tolerances, if you also factor in the calibration of the linearity of the device too. However, that is not a trivial matter especially when you factor in temperature variation.

If however you are trying to detect motion down in that range, the device, at least according to the limited information listed, is capable of detecting down to 1uG.

However, you are dealing with very small voltages and as such the signal to noise ratio becomes crucial. Reliably delivering such small analog signals over a quarter mile of cable is no trivial matter.

Your best solution here is to develop small PCBs that will fit on top of the sensor which will receive the analog signal, digitize it locally, then communicate with the central data gathering board via a suitable digital communication protocol. The complete sensor assembly can also be appropriately shielded to further reduce stray noise issues.

The local board can also clean up the power supply before delivering it to the sensor further improving the quality of the sensors output. Indeed over the quoted range it may be prudent to actually deliver a higher DC, or AC, voltage down the line and add regulators to power the sensors.

Comment: The challenges are 1-)For digital signals more than 100meters of CAT is not recommended(?) 2-) I will need 30 of those ADC modules, I dont think I can design them and take that risk for this... But is there a ready ADC module that can convert +-10V at 16 bit resolution? Something like Arduino board but with higher resolution and can accept negative voltages?

Comment: @newage2000 solving digital transmission >100m is not that hard. Finding an appropriate ADC is beyond the scope of this forum and answer.

Comment: Okay I will stick with analog for now. Just last question. Right now the 400m CAT cable is rolled with 1m diameter, I tested and the noise level is not bad. Im planning it to roll off it outdoors and check out. Maybe rolled cable delude me since it does not represent the real scenario where cable will be straight ?

Comment: By rolled I mean this: http://www.teamluco.co.za/image/cache/data/products/cable/takstar_cab053-340x340-800x580.jpg I onlt tested when the cable is this way in the room

Comment: @newage2000 coiled cable acts very differently from straight cable.. It does also depend on the cable run, what it passes close to or parallel to...

Comment: Oh I see so my test doesnt make sense right now.

Comment: @newage2000 ask yourself.. "Does my car radio work better with the antenna up.. or coiled in...?"

Comment: I got your point it will act as a log antenna when it is rolled off straight 400meter.

Comment: I found this module in case my analog way fails, http://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/AD7606_7606-6_7606-4.pdf

Comment: What kind of com interface thr ADC should have builtin for 400m distance? spi, i2c ect? Or again I need another circuitry to convert to R485 ect?

Comment: @newage2000 RS485 may be your best bet.. and yes you would need some form of transceiver. It depends a bit on the data/sample rate too though.

Comment: Ohoo I will have 30 accels. This solution will cost a fortune then.

Comment: @newage2000 I can't comment on that. If you have to use expensive shielded cable instead the cost may be a wash...